# The best way to assign an immutable instance to a Collection in Java

Tags: java, collections, immutability

Today I was reading through some Hibernate code and I encounter something interesting.
There is a class called CollectionHelper that defines the following constant varibale:

```
public final class CollectionHelper {

   public static final List EMPTY_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList( new ArrayList(0 ) ;
public static final Collection EMPTY_COLLECTION = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(new ArrayList(0) );
public static final Map EMPTY_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap( new HashMap(0) );
```

They have used these constants to initialize collections with immutable instances. Why they didn't simply use the Collections.EMPTY_LIST for initializing lists? Is there a benefit in using the following method?

Comment: @Ali: I don't know but not everyone is aware of every single detail of the Java APIs.  The other day I answered someone and made use of *Integer*'s *numberOfLeadingZeros(..)* method and some knowledgeable programmer commented that he didn't know about that method.  I'm not coming to SO or to the daily WTF posting everytime I encounter some piece of code re-inventing some part of an obscure Java API and calling that *"interesting".* It is not interesting, not much to see here besides hair-splitting, move along.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no benefit.  The only difference apparent to me is that this method is guaranteed to return a different `EMPTY_LIST` than any `List` created with `Collections.emptyList()`, whereas implemenations of `Collections.emptyList()` may or may not return the same `List` instances.  I am more inclined to agree with @WizardOfOdds's comment that they simply didn't know about those API functions.

Answer (score 0):

The may be times when it improves performance by reducing the number of implementations used at a particular call-site, allowing better monomorphic and bimorphic inlining optimisations. Bit of a long shot, though.